Perl SSH script sometimes sends the wrong password?
I have a bunch of old perl scripts that use SSH::Expect.  When they get to the $ssh->login() stage they occasionally appear to fail on the password prompt.  It will indicate a login failed and prompt for password again.
I havent been able to figure out why this started happening, but am wondering if there's a workaround. I'm not able to change to a different SSH model (like openssh etc) at this time due to the large # that use SSH::Expect.
If it is sending the first password attempt too quickly, is there a way to make sure it waits for the full prompt to appear?
If that 2nd password prompt appears, is there a way to get it to send the password again?
this is the relevant code:
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new (
            host => $deviceIpAddr,
            timeout => 3,
            log_stdout => 1,
            password=> $passwd,
            user => $username,
            ssh_option => '-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null',
);
$login_output = $ssh->login();


It currently waits for [Pp]assword.*?:|[Pp]assphrase.*?: before sending it. This can be overridden (by using ->login(qr/ogin:\s*$/, qr/[Pp]assword.*?:|[Pp]assphrase.*?:/)), but I don't see how that would be useful. That just leaves changing sub { $exp->send("$password$t"); } to sub { sleep(1); $exp->send("$password$t"); } in the code if speed is really the issue.

You might get some benefit from using ->login(1) (or the equivalent ->login(qr/ogin:\s*$/, qr/[Pp]assword.*?:|[Pp]assphrase.*?:/, 1)). It checks for a second password prompt and croaks if it gets one. You could catch that exception and try again.

Ok, so the ->login(1) would make it fail right away if a 2nd password prompt appears?  What about having it just put the password in again if that happens rather than failing? (saving me having to add an additional ->login() in there would be helpful given how many scripts I'd have to update)
